# ruby libxml : Where does returned node value come from?

Tags: ruby, libxml2, xpath-2.0

When parsing a XML document in Ruby with libxml, I receive too much data from a find XPath call.

My test data is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MAIN>
  <EPS>
    <EP ID="EDM01">EP 1
      <BP ID="EDM01_BP1">BP1 for EP1
        <Activities>
          <Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for EDM01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for EDM01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for EDM01_BP1</Activity>
        </Activities>
      </BP>
      <BP ID="EDM01_BP2">BP2 for EP1
         <Activities>
           <Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for EDM01_BP2</Activity>
           <Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for EDM01_BP2</Activity>
           <Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for EDM01_BP2</Activity>
         </Activities>
      </BP>
    </EP>
    <EP ID="APO01">EP 2
      <BP ID="APO01_BP1">BP 1 for EP2
        <Activities>
          <Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for APO01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for APO01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for APO01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="4">Activity 4 for APO01_BP1</Activity>
          <Activity ID="5">Activity 5 for APO01_BP1</Activity>
        </Activities>
      </BP>
    </EP>
  </EPS>
</MAIN>
```

And I parse it with:

```
xmlparser = XML::Parser.string(@strXML,:encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8)
@xmlDoc = xmlparser.parse
@projects = nil
project = nil
cl = @xmlDoc.find('/MAIN')
unless (cl.empty?)
  puts ""
  @projects = @xmlDoc.find('//EP [@ID]')
  @projects.each do |p|
    puts('<----------1--------->')
    puts(p.inner_xml)
    bps = p.find('//BP [@ID]')
    bps.each do |bp|
      puts('<----------2--------->')
      puts(bp.inner_xml)
      puts('<---- Activities ---->')
      acts = bp.find('//Activity [@ID]')
      acts.each do |act|
        puts('ActID> ' + act['ID'].to_s)
        puts(act.first.content.to_s)
      end
    end
  end
end
assert true
end
```

when looking at the displayed results, it shows that the fetched xml::node is correct (p.inner_xml)

```
<----------1--------->
EP 1      <BP ID="EDM01_BP1">BP1 for EP1<Activities><Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for EDM01_BP1</Activity><Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for EDM01_BP1</Activity><Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for EDM01_BP1</Activity> </Activities></BP><BP ID="EDM01_BP2">BP2 for EP1<Activities><Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for EDM01_BP2</Activity><Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for EDM01_BP2</Activity><Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for EDM01_BP2</Activity>         </Activities></BP>  
<----------2--------->
BP1 for EP1<Activities><Activity ID="1">Activity 1 for EDM01_BP1</Activity>          <Activity ID="2">Activity 2 for EDM01_BP1</Activity><Activity ID="3">Activity 3 for EDM01_BP1</Activity></Activities>
<---- Activities ---->  
ActID> 1  
Activity 1 for EDM01_BP1  
ActID> 2  
Activity 2 for EDM01_BP1  
ActID> 3  
Activity 3 for EDM01_BP1  
ActID> 1  
Activity 1 for EDM01_BP2  
ActID> 2  
Activity 2 for EDM01_BP2  
ActID> 3  
Activity 3 for EDM01_BP2  
ActID> 1  
Activity 1 for APO01_BP1  
ActID> 2  
Activity 2 for APO01_BP1  
ActID> 3  
Activity 3 for APO01_BP1  
ActID> 4  
Activity 4 for APO01_BP1  
ActID> 5  
Activity 5 for APO01_BP1
```

As you can see has the first XML node that is inspected only 3 activities.
But the program displays all activities from the complete xml doc. Not just from the fetched node.

Is it a wrong assumption that when doing a xmldoc.find() and traversing it with
    nodes.each do |n| 
the n variable is a libXML::XML::Node that is a subset from the xml document?
How is it otherwise possible to reference data (activities APOxxx) that is not part of the fetched node?

Comment: Changing the find statement to "Activities/Activity [@ID]" 'solves' the problem but not the question. In my opinion it is incorrect that a subset of a xml document (a fetched node) can return parts of the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines

```
bps = p.find('//BP [@ID]')
acts = bp.find('//Activity [@ID]')
```

with

```
bps = p.find('BP [@ID]')
acts = bp.find('Activities/Activity [@ID]')
```

XPath expressions starting with `/` or `//` are [*absolute* location paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) and always return all matching nodes below the root node regardless of the context node `p` or `bp`. This is similar to an absolute filesystem path that doesn't care about the current directory.

Comment: Thanks. This means however that in line with your example, when we refer to a directory as the new 'root', it still would be possible to reference the 'old root'. As I understand it now, traversing a xml document selection retrieved with a xpath query, using the ruby construction `nodes.each do |node|` does not return a XML node variable as being a copy of the inner_xml of the referenced node.